# chromedriver wont open url in second window / Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, discord.py

I am trying to open links which i get from my discord automatically with the selenium library. Here is my code:

```
    #imports 
    import discord
    from selenium import webdriver
    client = discord.Client()
    #Load discord channels
    def getChannelIDs():
    channelList = []
    with open ("C:\\Users\\haide\\PycharmProjects\\Discord-Link-Opener\\channel ID.txt", "r") as file:
        for id in file:
            channelList.append(int(id.strip()))
    return channelList

channelList = getChannelIDs()

#get the url from discord

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id in channelList:
        urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*(),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', message.content)
        if urls:
            print (f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Link(s) Found:")
            for x in range(len(urls)):
                print(urls[x])
                open_url(urls[x])

#open the link with selenium
def open_url(url):
 PATH = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'

 chrome_options = Options()
 chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium")
 chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=PATH)
 driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
 driver.maximize_window()
 driver.get(url) 
 client.run(token, bot=False)
```

Everything works perfectly fine until i get another link in my discord. It opens a second page but without the page is blank. I get also this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\haide\PycharmProjects\Discord-Link-Opener\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\haide\PycharmProjects\Discord-Link-Opener\DiscordLinkOpener.py", line 69, in on_message
    open_url(urls[x])
  File "C:\Users\haide\PycharmProjects\Discord-Link-Opener\DiscordLinkOpener.py", line 87, in open_url
    elif PartAlert in url:
  File "C:\Users\haide\PycharmProjects\Discord-Link-Opener\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\haide\PycharmProjects\Discord-Link-Opener\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\haide\PycharmProjects\Discord-Link-Opener\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\haide\PycharmProjects\Discord-Link-Opener\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\haide\PycharmProjects\Discord-Link-Opener\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir
```

Any ideas to fix that problem?

Comment: The error message tells you exactly how to fix that problem.  Right?

Comment: Actually you are right... I fixed this error but now it even doesnt start a second window if i get an url

Comment: So, you now provide a different `user-data-dir` value for each instance?  If that doesn't work, you've gone beyond what I know about Selenium.

Comment: doesn't seem like you need to keep creating new drivers.  You'll end up with a bunch of orphaned drivers you can't close here... can you just re-use the same one?  (you probably have a bunch of chromedrivers running in your tasks... end those tasks before retesting your code)

Comment: @TimRoberts actually i just changed the old one (=selenium) to a path of a new created profile. But this didnt actually solve my problem. I did some more tests and what i found out is when i remove ``` chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium")``` my code works out but this is still not what i want because i still need at least one profile running.

Comment: @pcalkins you mean like using the same chromedriver but using different tabs right? Is it though still possible to interact with all of the links if you wont create new drivers for each link?

Comment: yes, but not concurrently... not sure exactly what your requirements are here... one driver can switch between tabs/windows but you may want consider whether you need multiple tabs/windows.  If you need many things to happen at the same time then you would need one thread per driver per browser.

Comment: @pcalkins yea I need to do stuff at the same time so it would be the best if i have one thread per driver. That is what i tried to do yesterday but it seems like there isnt an official solution for that because as far as i know i would only be able to run one profile for only one thread and not for multiple threads

Comment: don't set any profile/user directories.  By default Selenium will create new temporary profiles for each instance.